# Trying to use Javascript to find text and link it to a page - possibly using XML as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have been working on this Fitment Guide that allows users to select their car and get the speaker sizes and locations. I've done this, what I haven't done is be able to make, say, "6.5" speakers" link to the page that displays said speakers. 
I would like to make this happen either directly in the XML file it searches, or with a script that finds "6x9" and links it to the 6x9 page. I've tried to use Xlink, but it fails to parse and makes my script quit functioning.

Here is a snippet of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ROWSET>
 <ROW>
 <MAKE>ACURA</MAKE>
 <Model>CL</Model>
 <YEAR>2001-
 2003</YEAR>
 <Front_Location_1>Door</Front_Location_1>
 <Front_Size_1>6 1/2</Front_Size_1>
 <Front_Location_2>Sail Panel</Front_Location_2>
 <Front_Size_2>1    </Front_Size_2>
 <Rear_Location_1>Deck</Rear_Location_1>
 <Rear_Size_1>6 x 9</Rear_Size_1>
 <Rear_Location_2></Rear_Location_2>
 <Rear_Size_2></Rear_Size_2>
 <Other_Speakers></Other_Speakers>
 </ROW>
```

And here is my script I use to search it and display the sizes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var $xml;

var make = $('#make');
var model = $('#model');
var year = $('#year');
var front1 = $('#Front_Location_1');
var frontsize1 = $('#Front_Size_1');
$.get('/content/fitguide3.xml', function(data){
    $xml = $(data);
    var rows = $(data).find('ROWSET ROW');
    var makes = [];

    $.each(rows, function(index, element){
        var _make = $(element).find('MAKE').text();
        makes.push('<option value="' + _make + '">' + _make + '</option>');
    });

    makes = $.unique(makes);
    make.append(makes.join('\n'));


}, 'xml');

$('#make').on('change', function(){
    var _value1 = $(this).val();
    var _models = $xml.find('ROWSET ROW:contains("'+_value1+'")');
    var models = [];

    console.log(_models);


    $.each(_models, function(index, element){

        var _model = $(element).find('Model').text();
        models.push('<option value="' + _model + '">' + _model + '</option>');
    });
    models = $.unique(models);
    model.find('option').remove();
    model.append(models.join('\n'));

});
$('#model').on('change', function(){
    var _value2 = $(this).val();
    var _years = $xml.find('ROWSET ROW:contains("'+_value2+'")');
    var years = [];

    console.log(_years);


    $.each(_years, function(index, element){

        var _year = $(element).find('YEAR').text();
        years.push('<option value="' + _year + '">' + _year + '</option>');
    });
    years = $.unique(years);
    year.find('option').remove();
    year.append(years.join('\n'));

});





//  $('#make').val()
//  $('#model').val()
//  $('#year').val()

$('#year').on('click', function(){  
    var _value3 = $(this).val();
    var finalmodel = $('#model').val();
    var finalfilter = $xml.find('ROWSET ROW:contains("'+finalmodel+'")');
    var _front1 = finalfilter.filter('ROWSET ROW:contains("'+_value3+'")');
    console.log(_front1);

    $.each(_front1, function(index, element){

        var _front = $('#frontspeakers').val();
        var front = [];  
        front.push('<p>' + element + '</p>');
        front = $.unique(front);
        front1.html(element);
    });


})

});
```

How I tried to use Xlink:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<ROW>
<MAKE>ACURA</MAKE>
<Model>CL</Model>
<YEAR>2001-
2003</YEAR>
<Front_Location_1>Door</Front_Location_1>
<Front_Size_1><65 xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://creativeaudio.net/6-5-speakers-1/">6 1/2</65></Front_Size_1>
```

Any solutions are welcomed and appreciated!

Comment: Is this available to check out at a live link somewhere?

Comment: yes! http://creativeaudio.net/vehicle-fit-guide/
I tried using an a tag in the xml since it is output as HTML anyway and it shows the link, but isn't clickable for some reason. try Acura TL 2007-2008

Answer (score 0):

Something about passing XML to `$.html()` seems to make the link in `<Front_Size_1>` render but not function.

Update line 84 at http://creativeaudio.net/content/fitguidescript.js from `front1.html(element);` to `front1.html($(element).html());` and you should find that the link will work.

BTW, the make/model/year selection is a bit buggy. If you change the model around the years don't seem to update themselves properly.

e.g.

1. select Acura TL
2. look at the years available to select
3. change model to Legend
4. change model back to TL
5. look at a different list of years than step 2